# Eclipse - servlet creation error

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am getting the following error when I try to use the Eclipse IDE wizard to create a Servlet:

```
"java.lang.Eror: Unresolved compilation problems:
   The import org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.common cannot be resolved.
   CreateServletTemplateModel cannot be resolved to a type
   ....
```

"

The settings of the IDE are as follows:

- Eclipse Version: 3.4.2
- WTP Servlet UI Plug-in: 1.1.203.v20081022000
  (org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui)

I don't have any problems manually creating the Servlets, I just would like the IDE to work as it's supposed to in order to avoid the overhead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg14897.html), that could be linked to a WTP installation issue.

Try to see if you still have the problem with:

- [WTP3.0.5](http://archive.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.0/R-3.0.5-20090521045405/) (compatible with your eclipse3.4.2)

or

- with the J2EE package (all-in-one distribution, see here for [ganymede - 3.4.2 - packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/))

Note: in both cases, you can duplicate your eclipse 3.4 installation, points to a fresh workspace and do your tests here (in order to avoid modifying anything from your current setup).